# Upgrading gcc in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image from docker file and at one point I run this command in the dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get upgrade gcc
```

when I build the image it will get to this point then stop building the image with the output below

```
91 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 65.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 7098 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get upgrade gcc' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 4):

`apt-get upgrade` tries to read user input from the standard input stream, which is not available during a Docker build. You can force `apt-get` into a non-interactive mode by using the `-y` (alternatively `--yes` or `--assume-yes`) flag:

```
RUN apt-get upgrade -y gcc
```

From [the manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get):

> **`-y`, `--yes`, `--assume-yes`**
>
> Automatic yes to prompts. Assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as changing a held package or removing an essential package, occurs then apt-get will abort.